# why Ctrl-c in gdb terminal dose not send STOP signal to gdb process

Tags: debugging, gdb, signals

To break loop in gdb  we need to Ctrl -c  in gdb terminal , but some time Ctrl-c  not working, is there a way to break the loop? ( excepted sending SIGSTOP or SIGTRAP to gdb process from another window)

The source code is something like that:

```
   main() {
   Initialize ():
   ...
   while (true)  //the main region of the program
   {
   ret = getmsg (fd, &ctrl, &data, &flags);
   Process (data);
   ...
   }
```

Comment: What loop are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Could you post some more specifics about the problem? Also why are trying to use ctrl-c to break inside of a loop instead of setting a break point?

To set a break point in gdb its as simple as running:

`b <a line number in the loop>`

here's some resources:

running this in gdb: `help break`

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints.html#Breakpoints

Comment: this is a OS and it's signals issue, but no break point, in fact we are in infinite loop and after enter C 'continue' in gdb , gdb freeze

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the requirement, but you could place a conditional breakpoint in the loop body if you don't want to break every time.
Now for your specific question, you can send the signal from within the gdb prompt, simply type :
 `signal SIGINT`.